# Removing a pattern from file names

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I have some files named as below:

```
e2ed150l145l245St01-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-0002105.omf
e2ed150l145l250St01-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-0002167.omf
e2ed150l145l255St01-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-0001519.omf
e2ed150l145l260St01-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-0001841.omf
e2ed150l145l265St01-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-0002730.omf
e2ed150l145l270St01-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-0002788.omf
e2ed150l145l275St01-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-0001616.omf
e2ed150l150l250St01-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-0002386.omf
e2ed150l150l2100St01-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-0015577.omf
```

I want to rename them to:

```
e2ed150l145l245St01.omf
e2ed150l145l250St01.omf
e2ed150l145l255St01.omf
e2ed150l145l260St01.omf
e2ed150l145l265St01.omf
e2ed150l145l270St01.omf
e2ed150l145l275St01.omf
e2ed150l150l250St01.omf
e2ed150l150l2100St01.omf
```

Following some of the similar forums I used several commands including:

```
rename 's/-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-[0-9]*//g' e2e*.omf -v
```

But it did not work. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `mv` as well:

```
for i in e2e*.omf; do
    mv $i ${i%%-*}.omf
done
```

or

```
for i in e2e*.omf; do
    mv $i ${i//-*/}.omf
done
```

To collapse to a single line:

```
for i in e2e*.omf; do mv $i ${i%%-*}.omf; done
```

If the destination already exists use `mv -f`

Comment: That is a part of **parameter expansion** being used for **substring extraction**. One of the most handy parts of bash. `${var##*x}` means **start at left** and remove everything, up to and including, `x`. (use one `#` for just the first occurrence). `${var%%x*}` is the same but **start at the right**. (**note:** how `*` changes position) Same note for one `%`. The second form `${var//x*/}` is **substring replacement**. Here it says find `x*` and replace it with **nothing**. True form is `${var//x/y/}`. With `y` being nothing -- the closing `/` is implied. HTH